# Why is my sinon stub not working and trying to make a external call?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mocking, sinon, stub

Hi I am working on making a unit test for AWS lambda written in JS.
To be honest, it is my first time writing a test.

I decided to use chai, mocha, and sinon libraries.
Here is my actual code

```
// index.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const getParam = async (path) => {
  const ssm = new AWS.SSM();
  const params = {
    Name: path,
    WithDecryption: false
  }
  
  const result = await ssm.getParameter(param).promise();
  const value = result['Parameter']['Value']
  console.log("@@", value);
  return value;
}
```

And here is what I got so far by reading other posts and documentation codes.

```
// index.test.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require("sinon");

const { getParam } = require('./index.js');

describe("test1", () => {
  if('testing', async () => {
    const ssm = AWS.SSM();
    sinon.stub(ssm, "getParameter").withArgs("testing")
      .resolve({ Parameter: { Value: "TESTING VALUE FROM PARAM STORE" } });

    const res = await getParam("Hello");

    console.log(res);
    expect("TESTING VALUE FROM PARAM STORE").to.equal("TESTING VALUE FROM PARAM STORE");
  })
})
```

When I ran the test, it asked for AWS secrets, which made me realize that it was not how I expected this to behave.

If it works correctly, it will not bother connecting to AWS at all, I believe.
And it should call `getParam` function and return the value from `resolve` function.
May I know what I am missing?

Or am I misusing stub function?
I read somewhere that stub function is used when we need to see what happened during the test like how many times a certain function was called and etc...
However, I saw some of the posts using the stub function to do a similar thing that I am doing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `SSM` inside your test and stubbing that, not the instance of `SSM` that lives inside your `getParam` method.

Instead, what you can do is stub against the prototype so that all instances from thereon will use stub when invoked.

```js
sinon.stub(AWS.SSM.prototype, "getParameter")
    .withArgs("testing")
    .callsFake(() => ({
        promise: Promise.resolve({ 
            Parameter: { 
                Value: "TESTING VALUE FROM PARAM STORE"
            } 
        })
    }));
```

You can't use `.resolves()` on `get Parameter` too as it doesn't return a promise, that's what you're `.promise()` chained method is responsible for, so we have to replicate this :).

Comment: Hi Thank you!! with detailed explanation. Now I have a better understanding.